# Swift 5 Alamofire 5 - Parse XML

Tags: swift, xml, alamofire, codable, parsexml

How can I parse an XML response from a network request using `swift 5` and `alamofire 5`?

This is the response I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd nbrfxrates.xsd">
    <Header>
        <Publisher>National Bank of Romania</Publisher>
        <PublishingDate>2020-08-12</PublishingDate>
        <MessageType>DR</MessageType>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Subject>Reference rates</Subject>
        <OrigCurrency>RON</OrigCurrency>
        <Cube date="2020-08-12">
            <Rate currency="AED">1.1186</Rate>
            <Rate currency="AUD">2.9324</Rate>
            <Rate currency="BGN">2.4724</Rate>
            <Rate currency="BRL">0.7634</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CAD">3.0904</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CHF">4.4964</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CNY">0.5916</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CZK">0.1846</Rate>
            <Rate currency="DKK">0.6494</Rate>
            <Rate currency="EGP">0.2566</Rate>
            <Rate currency="EUR">4.8357</Rate>
            <Rate currency="GBP">5.3638</Rate>
            <Rate currency="HRK">0.6466</Rate>
            <Rate currency="HUF" multiplier="100">1.3994</Rate>
            <Rate currency="INR">0.0549</Rate>
            <Rate currency="JPY" multiplier="100">3.8470</Rate>
            <Rate currency="KRW" multiplier="100">0.3470</Rate>
            <Rate currency="MDL">0.2478</Rate>
            <Rate currency="MXN">0.1842</Rate>
            <Rate currency="NOK">0.4582</Rate>
            <Rate currency="NZD">2.6941</Rate>
            <Rate currency="PLN">1.0966</Rate>
            <Rate currency="RSD">0.0411</Rate>
            <Rate currency="RUB">0.0562</Rate>
            <Rate currency="SEK">0.4710</Rate>
            <Rate currency="THB">0.1321</Rate>
            <Rate currency="TRY">0.5637</Rate>
            <Rate currency="UAH">0.1493</Rate>
            <Rate currency="USD">4.1087</Rate>
            <Rate currency="XAU">255.0694</Rate>
            <Rate currency="XDR">5.7841</Rate>
            <Rate currency="ZAR">0.2361</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </Body>
</DataSet>
```

What I need is the currency symbol and the value to be saved into an array of objects

```
struct CursValutar: Codable {
    let curs: [Currency]
}

struct Currency: Codable {
    let symbol: String
    let value: Double
}
```

I have tried some pods, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper). Your model will look like this:

```
struct DataSet: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var cursValutar: CursValutar?
    
    init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        cursValutar <- map["Body.Cube"]
    }
}

struct CursValutar: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var curs: [Currency]?
    
    init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        curs <- map["Rate"]
    }
}

struct Currency: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var symbol: String?
    var value: Double?
    
    init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        symbol <- map.attributes["currency"]
        value <- map.innerText
    }
}
```

You can fetch and map this XML like that:

```
AF.request(url).responseString { (dataResponse: AFDataResponse<String>) in
    switch dataResponse.result {
    case .success(let xmlString):
        let dataSet = XMLMapper<DataSet>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
        print(dataSet?.cursValutar?.curs?.first?.value)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a library like [XMLCoder](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder), which you can then use with Alamofire's `responseDecodable`:

```swift
// Make XMLDecoder conform to Alamofire's DataDecoder protocol.
extension XMLDecoder: DataDecoder {}
// Then you can use it to decode responses.
AF.request(...).responseDecodable(of: SomeType.self, decoder: XMLDecoder()) { response in
    //...
}
```